# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, orm

I have this bean in config

```
   @Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(
        DataSource dataSource    ) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    bean.setPackagesToScan("com.x");
    bean.setPersistenceUnitName("default");
    bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect");
    bean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    return bean;
}
```

And this for spring boot

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.x"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

How fix the issue?

Thx a lot!

Comment: Are your entities in the  `com.x`  package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Provide the Following to @EnableJpaRepositories annotation

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "defaultEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "defaultTransactionManager",
    basePackages = {"<complete package to dao package>"})
```

Comment: I added also an empty persistence.xml to fix this. Other solutions about EnableJpaRepositories does not work.(((

Comment: Can you please add these two annotation above as well
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"<base package for app>"})
    @EntityScan("<dao entity>")
These should be above @EnableJpaRepositories

and all these should be main method i.e starting point of Spring boot app